# Change adaptive brightness level programmatically

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, brightness, screen-brightness

How can I change the adaptive brightness level programmatically, on Android Lollipop?

I know how to change the manual `brightness level`, and to toggle on or off the `adaptive brightness`. It is done like that:
`Settings.System.putInt(cr, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, newLevel);`

However, with `adaptive brightness` is enabled, the OS combines it with another `brightness level` which is different than the manual one.

Is there a way to do this?

Target/min/max SDK is 21.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't know why but there is a hidden constant `SCREEN_AUTO_BRIGHTNESS_ADJ` in Android API to adjust adaptive brightness. But you can pass `"screen_auto_brightness_adj"` string value instead like I did.

Adaptive brightness adjustment is stored as float value in range [-1;1]. If you use brightness value in range [0;255], you can convert it to proper value as shown below.

```
float value = (((float)brightness*2)/255) - 1.0f;
Settings.System.putFloat(contentResolver, "screen_auto_brightness_adj", value);
```

Comment: This is the hidden setting I was looking for! Thanks @Ogix

Comment: I wanted to implement the same effect as that of adjusting the brightness slider on the quick settings drop down. This seems to work. But if it is hidden, does this mean Google does not want apps to adjust system brightness level when Adaptive brightness is set?

Comment: Setting "screen_auto_brightness_adj" worked on CyanogenMod, but did not work on Samsung's devices.

Comment: **UPDATE**: Accessing this URI throws SecurityException after API 24, as mentioned here: https://tunjid.medium.com/reverse-engineering-android-pies-logarithmic-brightness-curve-ecd41739d7a2

Answer (score 1):

If your app targetSdkVersion is 23+, Settings.System.putFloat(contentResolver, "screen_auto_brightness_adj", value) won't work as Android disables you to modify any "hidden" settings.

Read frameworks\base\packages\SettingsProvider\src\com\android\providers\settings\SettingsProvider.java warnOrThrowForUndesiredSecureSettingsMutationForTargetSdk() for details.